# How to remove unchanged values from a timestamped dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have the following CSV file:

```
Timestamp,Point,Value
2019-09-01,A,1
2019-09-01,B,2
2019-09-02,A,1
2019-09-02,B,2
2019-09-03,A,3
2019-09-03,B,4
2019-09-04,A,3
2019-09-04,B,4
2019-09-05,A,1
2019-09-05,B,2
```

I'm reading it on Spark 2.4.3 (Databricks 5.4 on Azure) using the following code:

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("/test-data/data.csv")
```

And I get a dataframe with the following schema:

```
df:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
  Timestamp:timestamp
  Point:string
  Value:double
```

This file contains a reading of the value of different "points" at different moments in time. In this example, A and B have readings every 1 day, but some of those values are the same as the previous reading.

I need to apply a transformation that will only leave rows whose Value column has changed from the previous reading for the same point.

```
|Timestamp |Point|Value|
|----------|-----|-----|
|2019-09-01|A    |1    | // A = 1
|2019-09-01|B    |2    | // B = 2 
|2019-09-02|A    |1    | // A unchanged, should be removed
|2019-09-02|B    |2    | // B unchanged, should be removed
|2019-09-03|A    |3    | // A = 3
|2019-09-03|B    |4    | // B = 4
|2019-09-04|A    |3    | // A unchanged, should be removed
|2019-09-04|B    |4    | // B unchanged, should be removed
|2019-09-05|A    |1    | // A = 1
|2019-09-05|B    |2    | // B = 2
```

In this simplified example, I'd want to get a dataframe like the following:

```
|Timestamp |Point|Value|
|----------|-----|-----|
|2019-09-01|A    |1    |
|2019-09-01|B    |2    |
|2019-09-03|A    |3    |
|2019-09-03|B    |4    |
|2019-09-05|A    |1    |
|2019-09-05|B    |2    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Spark 2.4.3 you could use Window function to achieve the desired result.

```
scala> var df_1= Seq(("2019-09-01","A",1),("2019-09-01","B",2),("2019-09-02","A",1),("2019-09-02","B",2),("2019-09-03","A",3),("2019-09-03","B",4),("2019-09-04","A",3),("2019-09-04","B",4),("2019-09-05","A",1),("2019-09-05","B",2)).toDF("Timestamp","Point","Value")

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


scala> df_1.show
+----------+-----+-----+
| Timestamp|Point|Value|
+----------+-----+-----+
|2019-09-01|    A|    1|
|2019-09-01|    B|    2|
|2019-09-02|    A|    1|
|2019-09-02|    B|    2|
|2019-09-03|    A|    3|
|2019-09-03|    B|    4|
|2019-09-04|    A|    3|
|2019-09-04|    B|    4|
|2019-09-05|    A|    1|
|2019-09-05|    B|    2|
+----------+-----+-----+

scala> val win = Window.partitionBy("Point").orderBy("Timestamp","Point","Value")
scala> val compareCols = List("Point", "Value")

scala> val df2 = df_1. withColumn("compCols", struct(compareCols.map(col): _*)). withColumn("rowNum", row_number.over(win)). withColumn("toKeep", when($"rowNum" === 1 || $"compCols" =!= lag($"compCols", 1).over(win), true). otherwise(false) )
scala> df2.filter(col("toKeep")===true).drop(col("compCols")).drop(col("rowNum")).drop(col("toKeep")).show
+----------+-----+-----+
| Timestamp|Point|Value|
+----------+-----+-----+
|2019-09-01|    B|    2|
|2019-09-03|    B|    4|
|2019-09-05|    B|    2|
|2019-09-01|    A|    1|
|2019-09-03|    A|    3|
|2019-09-05|    A|    1|
+----------+-----+-----+
```

let me know if you have any queries related to same.

Comment: This looks very promising. Will test it tomorrow at work and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @emzero ya sure

Comment: Thanks but it's not doing what I need. This seems to be doing some kind of distinct, because if the Value goes back to any of the values that had previously (but not the immediate previous value), it does still remove it. See my updated question to understand better what I'm saying.